# How to extract OAuth 2 token from non Azure/MS services

Tags: oauth-2.0, ms-word, office-js, office-addins

I have a big problem with development of Office add-in that is causing me big headache.
I need to extract the OAuth 2 token from a back-end written in Spring. I have tried all the samples from Microsoft Documentations, GitHub snippets and projects etc. Nobody works. Apart from MSAL Library that is extracting the token but the window is stuck in a loop of trying to login with Azure.
I know, this is not the correct way. But until now I haven't found any better solution yet. That's why I'm asking here.

Someone got a sample project? A snippet? Or something that could help me to do the job? Unfortunately, [office-js-helper](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-helpers) is abandoned. So I don't know what I can do.

Thanks

Comment: Tried with dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, processMessage); and still not working. The function is not executed.

Comment: Show your code and explain exactly what is going wrong.

Comment: Hi @RickKirkham, thanks for your reply. I have solved with Axios by passing code and execute a call to get the authorization code.